# Can there be any improvements in DFS traversal of graph code posted below?

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph

I want to improve efficiency of this DFS traversal code.

I intend to create a standard code for my self so that I can use it for online Competitive coding contests without any need to write whole thing again but just making few modifications in this code.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include<vector>
    using namespace std;
    void print_graph(const vector<vector <int> >GRAPH);
    void set_graph( vector<vector <int> >&GRAPH,const unsigned int sz);
    void DFS_Util(const vector<vector <int> >GRAPH,bool visted[]);
    void DFS(const vector<vector <int> >GRAPH,const unsigned int V);
    int main()
    {
    vector<vector <int > >GRAPH;
    int vertices;
    cin>>vertices;

      for(int i=0;i<vertices;i++)
        {   vector<int>temp(vertices,0);
          GRAPH.push_back(temp);
        }
    set_graph(GRAPH,GRAPH.size());

    print_graph(GRAPH);
    DFS(GRAPH,0);

        return 0;
    }

    void print_graph(const vector<vector <int> >GRAPH)
    {   int sz=GRAPH.size();
    for(int i=0;i<sz;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<sz;j++)
        {
          cout<<GRAPH[i][j]<<" ";
        }cout<<endl;
        }
    }
    void set_graph( vector<vector <int> >&GRAPH,const unsigned int sz)
    {
     for(unsigned int i=0;i<sz;i++)
        {
            for(unsigned int j=0;j<sz;j++)
        {
            int c;
            cin>>c;
    GRAPH.at(i).at(j)=c;
        }
        }
    }

    void DFS_Util(const vector<vector <int> >GRAPH,const unsigned int v,bool visted[])
    {
    visted[v]=true;
    cout<<" "<<v;

    for(unsigned int j=0;j<GRAPH.size();j++)
    {
     if(!visted[j]&&GRAPH[v][j]>=1)
       DFS_Util(GRAPH,j,visted);
    }

    }
    void DFS(const vector<vector <int> >GRAPH,const unsigned int V)
    {
        bool *visited=new bool[GRAPH.size()];
        for(unsigned int i=0;i<GRAPH.size();i++)
        {
            visited[i]=false;
        }

        DFS_Util(GRAPH,V,visited);

    }
```

Comment: this is either too broad (what kind of improvments do you mean?) or a good candidate for [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I want to improve space and time complexity of this code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, don't copy the graph for every call. Pass it by reference, especially since you don't modify it.

```
void DFS(const vector<vector <int> > & GRAPH,const unsigned int V)
void DFS_Util(const vector<vector <int> > & GRAPH,const unsigned int v,bool visted[])
```

You should see a large speedup just with those changes.